# Updating Paypal Preapproved payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I've integrated Adaptive Payments with Preapproval option to charge users periodically a given amount of money. I'd like to now give users an option to change the amount they're paying - looking through the PayPal documentation I can't seem to find any calls regarding modifying an existing Preapproval.

Is it indeed not possible to update a Preapproval, and the only option is to create a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you'll have to send the user through some sort of a flow again anyway to update their options, so you could just pull their current setup using [PreapprovalDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PreapprovalDetails_API_Operation/), then pre-populate an update form for the user using those details, let them adjust whatever they want to adjust, and then submit a new Preapproval request to create the new agreement based on the new options.

Comment: That's a real shame - PreapprovalDetails won't really help me much, as I already have all of that information. Oh well, thank you!